# Browserify not loading node modules in browser

Tags: browserify

I tried to use browserify to load my node modules to be used in browser. My main.js file depends on fs, cheerio, json-to-xlsx. When i bundle them using browsesrify, it bundles without any error. But when i load the bundled file,it always says cannot find module  'jszip', if i remove that dependency from my main.js and load, it shows same error with 'fs' module.

How do i use it? Or is there any other better loader to be tried to use node_modules on browser. i have tried webpack, wreq.js

[this is the error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUkbv.png)

Any assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The 'json-to-xlsx' module uses 'xlsx' module inside it. The xlsx.js uses 'jszip.js' like 'js'+'zip'. But browserify doesn't work with concatenation, hence you have to manually go and change the require('js'+'zip') to require('jszip').

Similar with the fs module also.